# Conexión web en Excel devuelve resultados antiguos

Tags: excel, web

Buenos días,

Tengo una conexión en Excel que recupera datos de una página web. Hasta hace poco funcionaba todo bien, recuperando los datos correctamente, tanto desde Excel, actualizando las conexiones, como desde vba (Querytable.refresh Background = false). Desde hace unos días, al intentar actualizar la conexión de datos, a pesar de no recibir ningún error, los datos que se muestran son antiguos y no se corresponden con los de la página web.

Es una excel de bolsa que usamos unos cuantos amigos y a todos nos ha pasado lo mismo, en diferentes ordenadores, en diferentes redes, ...

¿Alguna idea?

Gracias.

Comment: ¿Igual ha sido la web la que haya cambiado?

Comment: Si me conecto con el Explorer, Chrome o cualquier otro navegador, los datos que se muestran en la web son correctos.

Comment: Digo la manera en que la web trata esos datos, no se, es una idea.